# Column rearrange property for flex s:DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, advanceddatagrid, flex-spark

In my flex project there is a Spark s:DataGrid and now there is a new requirement to give the column rearrange property to it (User should be able to rearrange the order by grading columns). Due to overall project dependencies I'm not able to use mx components. Other wise I should have use mx:AdvancedDataGrid.

So how can I get the column rearrange property for the s:DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Then your project dependencies should be changed. In the rush to get Flex 4.x out the door, Adobe never fully developed the spark grid (notice the other grids are missing). I use a mix of both in any project I am in, and because skins/stylesheets were developed for mx-based grids to appear as spark-based, users nor most people on the project know any difference.